# Testing equality of proportions in multinomial variable (example from current US national polls)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multinomial-distribution

A recent CNN/ORC national telephone poll of US citizens for presidential elections has [resulted](http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2016/images/09/05/rel13a.-.2016.post-labor.day.pdf) in the following propotion estimates $\hat{p}$ of votes by likely voters for Clinton (C), Trump (T), and other candidates: $\hat{p}_C=.43$, $\hat{p}_T=.45$, $\hat{p}_{other}=.12$, where sample size was $n=886$. How should we test

$H_0: p_T \le p_C$ against $H_1: p_T > p_C$

If we had a binomial variable, the situation would be equivalent to testing whether $p_T$ differs from $0.5$. How should we deal with the "other" category?

Given the fact that the sample here is much smaller than the population and that we have no available information on the type of sampling design (and the fact that we have aggregate statistics only), I think we may ignore finite population correction and sampling weight issues.

**Edit** I found [here](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/09/08/understanding-the-margin-of-error-in-election-polls/) an obvious workaround by PEW research center by using confidence intervals. Still I would be interested in a test.